# NETSEND from Java?

Tags: java, windows, shell

Is it possible to get access to the shell to do a netsend from java? So that I can send an alert to the screen of a pc at a particular IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it but net service is disabled by default.

```
 Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process pr = run.exec( "net send ip msg" );
 pr.waitFor();
```

Comment: Do you mean that it's disabled on a machine? I think it's active on all the machines on our network because it's in use in php.

Comment: I ment a clean installation of any updated windows version have that service disabled but it's easy to enable. I think it was "net start messenger" or if you want it to start every boot you can set it to automatic in msconfig

Comment: Yes, that was what I ment. Ok, yes a lot of companies enable that feature because it's necessary in many business solutions.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the solution. Worked perfect. Our company does find it super useful for paging staff to the factory floor.